# Prevent Spring From Committing Entity Changes Made In The Controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am loading an entity from service layer for edit using below code snippet.

```
public class VendorServiceImpl{

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
Vendor findVendor(...){
return vendorRepository.findVendorBy(...);
}

}

    @Controller
    VendorController{

       @AutoWired
       VendorService vendorService;

       @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
       public String editVendor(@PathVariable("id")Long id){
         Vendor v =   vendorService.findVendorBy(id);
         /*
          After loading the entity from db I want to make a few changes
          e.g 
          v.setCountry("xyz");
         This change is automatically sent to the database which I don't       want.
         /*
       }
}
```

How can I prevent this issue. I want to commit changes once the user submits the form.

I am using spring 4.3.7 and hibernate 5.0.12

Comment: Have you enabled Transaction Management ?

Comment: Making changes should be done in your service nor your controller, that is business logic which belongs in the service layer. Your controller should only be a thin translation layer from outside communication to inside service calls. If you are changing data because you want to hide it from expose you are in need of a DTO or proper configuration of your marshaling framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, but OP doesn't need to change them in the service layer and if you do so, object will be synced... OP is curious about the sync where it cannot be happening. So it would be a configuration problem sometimes. And yes, if OP need to update values it should be done in service layer/business, not in the controller.

Comment: He shouldn't be changing things in the controller in the first place especially not on a GET request and especially not when you are using managed entities. That is 2 times a no-go ... However this can only arise if there are no or wrong transaction management combined with an `Open[EntityManager|Session]InView[Filter|Interceptor]`.

Comment: I have OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter confugred in web.xml as follows <filter>
        <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>persistenceUnitName</param-name>
            <param-value>medequipPU</param-value>
        </init-param> 
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: How should it be configured?

Comment: I am making changes in the controller to force users to make some changes.

Comment: I have enable transaction management using     <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
 in the root context

Answer (score 0):

Does set country make a database call, if so then ideally DB calls should not be made from entities but from the service layer since handling from the entity layer would be problematic. However if you are unable to change this then I would recommend that you create a transaction around your controller. That should ensure that once the transaction in your controller is completed only then values are commited.

Also as a practice ensure that the autocommited property of the connection is set to false.

Comment: setCounty is a setter in the Vendor class. It is not making a database call.

Comment: Then how is setCountry("xyz") going to the database...where is the database call being made